# How to merge collection with same user id in Laravel and get his average grade

Tags: laravel

I need to merge collection with same user id in Laravel and get his average grade, because now my app display two records instead of one if he has 2 grades and I want to fix this somehow.. Here is my laravel code:

```
@foreach($grades->sortByDesc('grade')->take(10) as $grade)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @if($grade->user_id == Auth::id())
                <strong>{{ $grade->user->first_name . " " . $grade->user->last_name }}</strong>
            @else
                ...
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">{{ round($grade->where('user_id', $grade->user_id)->where('module_id', $module->id)->avg('grade'), 2) }}</div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

So I want this result:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy()`:

```
@foreach ($grades->sortByDesc('grade')->take(10)->groupBy('user_id') as $userGrades)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @if($grade->user_id == Auth::id())
                <strong>{{ $userGrades->first()->user->first_name . ' ' . $userGrades->first()->user->last_name }}</strong>
            @else
                ...
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">{{ round($userGrades->where('module_id', $module->id)->avg('grade'), 2) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Or you can just load users with grades:

```
$users = User::with('grades')->get();
```

And then:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->grades->avg('grade') }}
@endforeach
```